# eclipse ADT : now i can transfer application to install on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adt

how adt knows that emulator is now fully loaded and i can transfer application now for installation?

**Edit:**

I am trying to develop a batch file which first create avd, start emulator with that avd, then install my application (.apk) to emulator running my avd.

But install apk (ie. adb install my.apk) requires fully loaded emulator. (even adb wait-for-device doest not help in this case).

So I was asking about how ADT knows that device is fully loaded. So i can implement same thing in my bat file and automate the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to run your application, ADT should automatically detect connected devices and/or emulators and allow you to choose which one to upload to. There is no need to manually transfer or install anything.